# After adding a new Assembly File the "Volume" class is no longer found

Tags: unity, unity-urp, assembly

I added a new assembly file to a folder containing my Unity scripts. After setting the Assembly Definition References all Classes of other assemblies are found except `Volume`.

```
The type or namespace name 'Volume' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What assembly do I have to link to be able to use `Volume`?

Answer (score 1):

The `Volume` class is part of the `UnityEngine.PostProcessing` namespace, so you will need to add a reference to the `UnityEngine.PostProcessing` assembly in order to use it.